# Python socket returning different IP address for the same host name in local and server

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets

I am trying to get the IP address from the domain name, the problem is it gives a different IP address when the code is running locally and on the server.

Here is my code and the result when running on local

```
import socket
domain_str="use.typekit.net"
ip = socket.gethostbyname(domain_str.strip())
print(ip)
```

```
output > '104.86.189.35'
```

Here is the result of the same code running on the server

```
output > '62.115.253.9'
```

I would really appreciate it if anyone could let me know why this is happening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The server you are trying to reach is behind the Akamai CDN. Depending on where you connect from this CDN might give you a different IP address for optimal connectivity.

For example I get from one location:

```
$ dig use.typekit.net
...
use.typekit.net.        121     IN      CNAME   use-stls.adobe.com.edgesuite.net.
use-stls.adobe.com.edgesuite.net. 5853 IN CNAME a1988.dscg1.akamai.net.
a1988.dscg1.akamai.net. 133     IN      A       89.27.242.17
a1988.dscg1.akamai.net. 133     IN      A       89.27.242.41
```

while from another location

```
use.typekit.net.        28      IN      CNAME   use-stls.adobe.com.edgesuite.net.
use-stls.adobe.com.edgesuite.net. 21568 IN CNAME a1988.dscg1.akamai.net.
a1988.dscg1.akamai.net. 5       IN      A       104.114.77.65
a1988.dscg1.akamai.net. 5       IN      A       104.114.77.32
```

If you do a [GeoIP lookup](https://www.maxmind.com/en/geoip-demo) of these addresses you will see one of your addresses located in India while the other one in Sweden.

Comment: https://www.site24x7.com/find-website-location.html,  Can you tell me how this website getting the correct location,  is there any python implementation

Comment: is there a way I could get the same IP address on server

Comment: @MohamedAbdullah. What you get in DNS lookup depends on the DNS server, not on your server. You maybe can get a different IP if you tunnel from your server to another system to make the DNS lookup from there, like with a VPN. But you likely could use the other IP for accessing the site even if it was not returned by the DNS lookup from your location. But why do you want not use  the fastest access which Akamai likes to give you?

Comment: *"Can you tell me how this website getting the correct location, is there any python implementation"* - This is a different topic. Please stay in the scope of your original question. But just search for "geoip python" if you want a python implementation.

Comment: I have used geoip python, but the problem is the changing IP address on local and server, is there a way to get consistent IP address on the server same as local

Comment: @MohamedAbdullah: hard code it :( As long as you depend on some DNS service to resolve it you depend on this service to provide you with the answer it thinks is appropriate for you. But it might be a problem if your application needs a consistent IP address when running from arbitrary places since these IP might change even for the same place. So better redesign your app and remove this dependency.

Comment: Can you tell me how you are telling use.typekit.net is behind a CDN

Comment: @MohamedAbdullah: see that reference to Akamai in the output of the DNS lookups I've included in my question? That shows that it is using the Akamai CDN.